Is there a word or a phrase for faking a laugh
I want to know how to describe someone faking a laugh without having to say "faking a laugh"

Thanks! I added it on there.

You can write "a forced laugh", or "an insincere laugh."
or "insincerely laughing."
Other synonyms are "overdone laugh", or "hollow laugh," or "pretended laugh" depending on your taste.

A titter, snort, or a staccato "ha-ha", could easily be perceived as insincere or dismissive laughter. Often when a character laughs at an inappropriate time at a character who is being serious, intentional or not, can be perceived as hurtful to the recipient of such attention.
Show the person's reaction to the laugher, or have someone else that is close to them react negatively towards the laugher if their friend or mate seems clueless towards the "obvious" insult.
Edit: Adding another obvious word... scoff.

hardy har har
